# R dataframe - transpose month column to 12 separate columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Probably this is a stupid question, but I can't figure out how to transfer this dataframe in R:

```
employee <- c('John Doe','John Doe','Jolie Hope','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(2100,2200,1900,1800)
month <- c("January","Febraury","January","Febraury")
employee.data <- data.frame(employee,salary,month)
```

To this one in R:

[image]

Of course I can change the construction of the dataframe in this example. However my real data has another source ;). Therefore I would like to do this with some simple commands.

Comment: You are right jogo, this is a duplicate. thank you for your reply.

Comment: Try `reshape(employee.data, idvar = "employee", timevar = "month", direction = "wide")`

Comment: Or you can do it the tidyverse way: `employee.data %>% spread(month, salary)`

Comment: The tidyverse way gives me an error: Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 4 rows: